# Оборот "ну и конечно же" - как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

И еще один непонятный для меня вопрос в тексте. Предложение такое: *"Ну и конечно же, отдых на одном из живописных пляжей Черного моря".*
Я бы тут выделил "конечно же" запятыми как вводный оборот, но меня поправили, что запятая должна быть одна, после всей конструкции "ну и конечно же". Разве это правильно? Почему "конечно же" само по себе не выделяется запятыми в качестве вводного?

Answer (score 5):

Правильно:  "Ну и конечно же, отдых на одном из живописных пляжей Черного моря".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом,  так как  вводное слово тесно примыкает к союзу:   "И действительно, мы больше не встречались.  А впрочем, как вам угодно; выстрел ваш остается за вами. Да кроме того, выяснились и другие подробности дела. Но конечно, его трудно было переубедить".

В приведенном примере мы имеем сочетание: частица НУ + присоединительный союз И + вводное слово.

Answer (score 2):

"Ну и" - усилительная частица. А усилительные частицы при вводных словах не отделяются от них запятой (такое правило):

*Уж вероятно, это так, поскольку нет никаких противопоказаний.*