# Сочетания "союз + вводное слово", первая запятая

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Время от времени возникает один и тот же вопрос, как обособляются такие сочетания, первая запятая ставится непосредственно перед вводным словом или выделяются союз с ним вместе. Например, *"и конечно", "и наконец".* Как с ними быть? Или *"хотя конечно"?*

Нашёл в очередной раз [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/36724/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5) вопрос и перечитал ответ Софии. Очень хочется верить, что она всё правильно говорит, что присоединительный союз не отделяется от вводного слова запятой. Только подтвердите, пожалуйста, что она права, чтобы мне быть на 300% уверенным и не колебаться каждый раз, когда пишешь.

Поразмышляв, я сделал следующее предположение. Может, союз сливается с вводным словом в тех случаях, когда перед ним по другим причинам нужна запятая, но не сливается (запятая ставится непосредственно перед вводным словом) в случае с однородными членами? Например, *"и днём и, конечно (же), ночью"* или *"ни Петя, ни Ваня, ни, конечно (же), Вася".* В случае с "ни" запятая перед "конечно", несмотря на запятую перед "ни" (Мне так кажется, может я и неправ).

Как бы то ни было, но, возможно (Как, кстати в этом случае? Мне кажется либо как у меня, либо "но возможно, *что* это" (член предложения)), это лишь маленькая часть всех случаев, когда эти трудности могут возникнуть, поэтому хотелось бы услышать правило, которое было бы как можно шире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правило таково:

Вводное слово (сочетание) отделяется от предшествующего сочинительного союза (как правило, *и, но*) запятой, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.

> Весь тираж уже отпечатан, и, вероятно, книга на днях поступит в продажу;

Если же изъятие или перестановка вводного слова невозможна, то запятая после сочинительного союза не ставится (обычно при союзе *а*):

> А впрочем, беды большой нет, если до Рейна ничего не увидишь (Герц.).
>
> Мы знаем, а стало быть, верим, что сказкам сбываться дано (Мих.).

Но если изъятие или перестановка вводного слова возможна, то запятая ставится и после союза а, поскольку он не связан с вводным словом (т. е. не образуются спаянные сочетания типа *а значит, а впрочем, а следовательно*):

> Для них он герой, а, признаться сказать, я себе героев иначе представляю (Т.);
>
> Ср. также: Хорошо или плохо, а по мне, делай что хочешь — **союз а связан с сочетанием по мне;** Собака не идёт в конуру, а, похоже, скрывается — **союз а не связан с вводным словом похоже.**

Между присоединительным союзом **(в начале самостоятельного предложения)** и **вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая обычно не ставится,** так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову:

> **И в самом деле, послышались голоса внизу (Ч.).**

И действительно, всё у него получалось удивительно вовремя (Кав.).

Иногда **(при интонационном выделении вводных слов или предложений, при их включении в текст посредством подчинительного союза)** после присоединительного **союза запятая перед вводной конструкцией ставится:**

> **Но, к великой моей досаде,** Швабрин… решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша (И.); И, как водится, вспоминали только одно хорошее (Крым.).

Постановка запятой позволяет разграничить вводное сочетание и независимое предложение в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения. Ср.:

> Однако, кажется, решение задачи ошибочное **(вводное слово)**. — Однако кажется, решение задачи ошибочное (**безличное предложение в составе бессоюзного сложного);**

Но, я вижу, вам это не подходит **(вводное предложение).** — Но я вижу, вам это не подходит **(бессоюзное сложное предложение).**

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь, Д. Э.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Великолепный ответ!! Всё это чувствуется интуитивно, но приятно, что есть где проверить свою интуицию или подтвердить собственное ощущение.

Answer (score 0):

> > **Запятая *обычно* не ставится между присоединительным союзом и вводным словом...**

Видите? ОБЫЧНО не ставится. А вы хотите быть уверенным на 300 процентов и не колебаться. Не колебаться не получится! Все колеблются! Читайте, изучайте, занимайтесь. Тогда постепенно и придет уверенность. Более-менее уверенность...

Comment: Так я и хочу, чтобы мне в ответах разъяснили эти нюансы!..