# Правильная расстановка запятых при "может быть"

Tags: пунктуация

"Может быть, скучно, а, может быть, и нет".

Меня смущает расстановка запятых.

Есть ли в данном случае лишние запятые?

Comment: Для справки, подобный вопрос уже был: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422857/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

Правильно смущает. После союза *а* перед вводным “может быть” запятая лишняя. Вводное не может быть изъято из предложения без ущерба для смысла.

[Правило обособления вводных слов и предложений имеет несколько очень важных примечаний.](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_189)

> Если перед вводным словом стоит союз А или НО, то запятая между
>   вводным словом и союзом ставится не всегда. Сравните пару предложений:
>
> *Врач закончил прием, но, конечно, тяжелого больного посмотрит.*
>
> *Он дал слово, а следовательно, должен его сдержать.*
>
> Вводное слово можно переставить или убрать без союза только в первом
>   случае, поэтому между вводным словом и союзом необходима запятая. Во
>   втором предложении это сделать невозможно, а значит, запятая не
>   cтавится.

Answer (score 0):

***а(,) может быть***
1. *Союз + вводное выражение (то же, что «возможно, вероятно»).*
1.1. Если слова «может быть» («быть может») можно изъять или переместить, то они выделяются с двух сторон знаками препинания, обычно запятыми:

*...всегда считала вас далеко не подлецом, **а, может быть,** гораздо лучше других... мерзавцев!..*
(Ф. Достоевский, "Бесы")
*Я вот женатый человек и в летах, **а, может быть,** в этом отношении тоже не без греха...*
(А. Писемский, "Горькая судьбина")

1.2. Если же исключить или переставить слова «может быть» («быть может») нельзя, то запятая между «а» и «может быть» («быть может») не ставится:

*Шкипер часто закивал, **а может быть,** у него затряслась голова.*
(А. и Б. Стругацкие, "Хромая судьба")
***А может быть,*** она и не умерла?
(Д. Хармс, "Старуха")

Итак, ***запятая после союза ставится,*** если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.
Если же изъятие вводного слова невозможно (т. е. союз включается во вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание), ***то запятая после союза не ставится.***
[**Пунктуация при вводных словах и сочетаниях, п.3. *Вводное слово и союз***](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/605/%E2%86%91%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_2)

В Вашем предложении правильно так:
***Может быть, скучно, а может быть, и нет.***