# Пунктуация в конструкции «но к сожалению»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, союзы

Правильно будет ***"но, к сожалению, результаты еще не готовы"*** или ***"но к сожалению, результаты ещё не готовы"***?
Какой вариант пунктуации правильный?

Answer (score 3):

1. Если эта фраза является частью сложного предложения, то вводное сочетание ***к сожалению*** выделяется с обеих сторон.

> Запятая после союза ставится, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.
>
> *Она очень долго страдала после разлуки, **но, как известно,** время лечит любые раны.*

2. Если эта фраза — отдельное предложение, начинающееся с союза и вводного слова, то возможны оба варианта пунктуации.

> Вводное слово обычно не отделяется знаком препинания от присоединительного союза, стоящего в начале предложения.
>
> ***Да кроме того,** он уже и сделал кое-что путное.* Д. Гранин, Зубр.
>
> **Примечание**. При интонационном выделении вводного слова оно может отделяться запятой от союза: ***Но, к великой моей досаде,** Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша.* А. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

См: [ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

Comment: Я считаю, что в  этом ответе  ОЧЕНЬ ВЕРНО указано на ИНТОНАЦИОННОЕ  выделение вводного слова, что как раз и имеет решающее значение. При отделении от союза вводное слово  подчеркивается, выделяется, что как раз и соответствует авторскому решению. Если же вводное слово не отделять от присоединительного союза запятой, то все сочетание приобретает присоединительный характер, а значимость вводного слова становится  меньше.

Comment: @Sharon А как быть с интонацией, когда эта конструкция внутри предложения? Ведь правило вынуждает ставить запятую вопреки интонации: скорее, вариант с интонационным выделением яляется нарочитым риторическим приемом (в нейтральном случае паузы не возникает - по смыслу противопоставляется _сожаление_, которое затем раскрывается, - чем не присоединительная конструкция вместо вводной?).

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуационное оформление этой хитрой конструкции (**сочинительный союз + вводное слово/сочетание**) неоднократно рассматривалось на форуме.
Вот, как мне кажется, самый полный ответ, в котором автор рассмотрел все возможные ситуации, связанные с постановкой запятой:
[Сочетания “союз + вводное слово”, первая запятая](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422857/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F).

Не будем пересказывать правила — рассмотрим примеры.
Да, в сложносочиненном предложении конструкция «но, к сожалению» **в с е г д а** должна иметь в своем составе запятую:
Эту поэму Иван Николаевич сочинил, и в очень короткий срок, **но, к сожалению,** ею редактора нисколько не удовлетворил. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]; С интересом он смотрит только вперёд, **но, к сожалению,** он увидит немногое. [Юрий Трифонов. Обмен (1969)].

Интересно, что в [**Нацкорпусе**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&endyear=2019&p=4) «Но, к сожалению» (в начале предложения) тоже имеет запятую — в подавляющем большинстве случаев:
**Но, к сожалению,** как и в любой профессии, находятся среди адвокатов те, кто это правило нарушает. [Александра Маринина. Ангелы на льду не выживают. Т. 1 (2014)];
**Но, к сожалению,** этот вид просветления можно описать только в терминах квантовой механики. [А. А. Ботев. Кот Шредингера // «Волга», 2013].

Выбор — ставить или не ставить запятую? — зависит от контекста и, конечно же, от [авторского замысла](https://gorky.media/context/shevchuk-vzyal-svoe-delo-iz-ruk-shostakovicha/):

> Моя идея заключалась в том, что и тот, и другой представляют социальные проблемы в музыке, которые должны обязательно ставиться, потому что музыка — это активное искусство. **Но к сожалению,** после Шостаковича отечественная музыка как-то обходит социальные проблемы стороной, молодые композиторы уходят в абстракции.

Answer (score 1):

Это не ответ, **а комментарий для Alex_ander**  (об интонации вводных слов)

Интонационная тема для вводных слов вообще очень интересная.  Вводные слова по **смыслу** составляют **второй план речи**, в то же время существует **интонация второго плана,** которую называют **вставочной**. Для нее используются определенные приемы: общее понижение тона, изменение темпа речи, выделение паузами различной длительности. Если оборот речи обособляется **в середине предложения**,  то он имеет названные выше признаки.

С другой стороны,   обороты **в начале предложения**  вставками не назовешь – они или образуют **самостоятельную фразу** с собственным ударением, или **входят в состав первой фразы,** только частично выделяясь внутри нее произносительной паузой (так обычно происходит с обстоятельственными оборотами-детерминантами).

В художественном тексте деление речи на два плана особенно заметно. ***НО, к великой моей досаде,**  // Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, решительно объявИл, // что песня моя нехорошА.* Я полагаю, что здесь три основные фразы, причем сочетание «*нО, к великой моей досАде*» составляет **самостоятельную фразу** с тоническим ударение на союзе НО, поэтому **статус ее значимости высок** (на втором же плане здесь дается обособленное определение).

Сравним (пример у Риммы):  ***Но к сожалению, после Шостаковича**/ отечественная музыка как-то обходит / социальные проблемы сторонОй, // молодые композиторы уходят в абстрАкции.*

Это БСП, причем первая фраза значительно распространена, и ее приходится **делить на части (синтагмы) произносительными паузами**. И вот первый отрезок – это «*но к сожалЕнию, после ШостакОвича»*.  Здесь самостоятельность у вводного слова **минимальная:**  выделение обычным  (не фразовым) ударением  обоих слов при практически отсутствующей паузе.

Таким образом, мы видим, как реальная интонация вводных слов во многом зависит от **общей структуры** предложения.  **Наличие запятой** после союза НО во втором примере **помешало бы** прочтению предложения.